# RUN service nginx restart fails when building docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

My goal is to put a website in a docker image and run it. Below is my docker file order

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install nginx -y

COPY . /var/www/my-website

COPY server.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/server.conf

EXPOSE 9999

RUN service nginx restart

CMD nginx "-g daemon off;"
```

so now when I run the command `docker build . -t packagesite:latest` on windows powershell it fails to process RUN service nginx restart.

```
 => ERROR [6/6] RUN service nginx restart                                                                          0.5s
------
 > [6/6] RUN service nginx restart:
#0 0.383  * Restarting nginx nginx
#0 0.406    ...fail!

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c service nginx restart" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I tried checking permission and it was okay

I tried starting and restarting the nginx service in ubuntu and it works. There is also no syntax errors in the nginx configuration file. I've been stuck here for an hour I need help.

Answer (score 1):

A Docker container only runs a single process; by default the thing you list as the `CMD`.  That process isn't running during the image build, so there's no need to "restart the server" because you provided a different configuration for it.  More broadly, commands like `service` or `systemctl` or `/etc/init.d` scripts tend to just not work in Docker, and you should never need to run them.

In the Dockerfile you've shown, you provide the configuration and content already, along with a `CMD` to start the Nginx server.  It should be enough to delete the `RUN service nginx restart` line.

Depending on your needs and compliance requirements, you could also consider using the prebuilt [Docker Hub `nginx` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).  That already includes Nginx and the configuration to run it, so you just need to `COPY` your content in:

```bash
FROM nginx:1.25
COPY ./ /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY server.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/server.conf
# no EXPOSE or CMD lines required, these are in the base image
```